# Creating a Connection String in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My connection string fails with the error

> "Invalid Connection String Attribute"

```
ConnString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server= datawarehouse; Database= Customers; USERID= Span1;Password= Span2;"
```

Comment: It's a pretty straight forward error message - what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @MacroMan you merely got the parameters wrong. Try the following instead:

```
 conSQLServerDB.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; " _
        & "DATA SOURCE=DateWarehouse; " _
        & "INITIAL CATALOG=Customers; " _
        & "User ID=Span1;" _
        & "Password=Span2"
```